# How I should combine static + non-static content using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm very new to Cake and I'm not fully understand how I should combine content.

I have 5-6 static pages, they are serving by default Pages Controller, so they are opening by link example.com/pages/page_name and I only made views for them.

But for some of this pages I want to add CRUD functionality.

> ```
> For example:
>   example.com/pages/index - static
>   example.com/pages/news - have CRUD
>   example.com/pages/about - static
>   etc.
> ```

How I see the solution of this problem:
1. Make model + controller for pages that needs CRUD, and then route with

Router::connect('/pages/news', array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'display'));

Am I right or there is a different and more correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the PagesController from the cake/libs/controllers directory into your app/controllers directory and use it like any other controller. You can create a `function news` in it that loads a model (`$this->loadModel()`) or just generally include a model in the PagesController like any regular controller.

It may be a better idea to make a dedicated NewsController, but that's up to you and how you want to organize your app. As you say, you can "alias" the URL pointing to the NewsController to something else if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP is an MVC framework which stands for : Model,View,Controller. So basically, every request you make should go through a controller that will roughly do the following:

1. If request requires data from DB -> get it from Model and pass it to view with data from model.
2. If request don't need extra data, pass on to appropriate view.

So to answer your question: yes, you need to have a 'news' controller and a 'news' model, and you need to register that controller and pass the data to the view once you get it from the model.

Comment: redirect might not be the best word here (could be mistaken for actual redirects) - better use "pass on to". but other than that spot on

Comment: Tahnks, changed according to your suggestion